# How to read text in XSLFGraphicFrame with Apache POI for PowerPoint

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm making a Java program to find occurrrences of a particular keyword in documents. I want to read many types of file format, including all Microsoft Office documents.

I already made it with all of them except for PowerPoint ones, I'm using Apache POI code snippets found on StackOverflow or on other sources.
I discovered all slides are made of shapes (XSLFTextShape) but many of them are objects of class XSLFGraphicFrame or XSLFTable for which I can't use simply the toString() methods. How can I extract all of the text contained in them using Java.
This is the piece of code\pseudocode:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Windows\\Desktop\\Modulo 9.pptx");
PrintStream out = System.out;

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(is);
for (XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide) {
       if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
       XSLFTextShape txShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
       out.println(txShape.getText());
       } else if (shape instanceof XSLFPictureShape) {
        //do nothing
       } else if (shape instanceof XSLFGraphicFrame or XSLFTable ) {
       //print all text in it or in its children
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement "to find occurrences of a particular keyword in documents" needs simply searching in all text content of `SlideShows`, then simply using [SlideShowExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/extractor/SlideShowExtractor.html) could be an approach. This also can act as entry point to an [POITextExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/extractor/POITextExtractor.html) for getting  textual content of the document metadata / properties, such as author and title.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.SlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor;

import org.apache.poi.extractor.POITextExtractor;

public class SlideShowExtractorExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow<XSLFShape,XSLFTextParagraph> slideshow 
   = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("Performance_Out.pptx"));

  SlideShowExtractor<XSLFShape,XSLFTextParagraph> slideShowExtractor 
   = new SlideShowExtractor<XSLFShape,XSLFTextParagraph>(slideshow);
  slideShowExtractor.setCommentsByDefault(true);
  slideShowExtractor.setMasterByDefault(true);
  slideShowExtractor.setNotesByDefault(true);

  String allTextContentInSlideShow = slideShowExtractor.getText();

System.out.println(allTextContentInSlideShow);

System.out.println("===========================================================================");

  POITextExtractor textExtractor = slideShowExtractor.getMetadataTextExtractor();
  String metaData = textExtractor.getText();

System.out.println(metaData);

 }
}
```

Of course there are kinds of `XSLFGraphicFrame` which are not read by `SlideShowExtractor` because they are not supported by `apache poi` until now. For example all kinds of [SmartArt graphic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-smartart-graphic-fac94c93-500b-4a0a-97af-124040594842). The text content of those is stored in `/ppt/diagrams/data*.xml` document parts which are referenced from the slides. Since `apache poi` does not supporting this until now, it only can be read using low level underlying methods.

For example to additionally get all text out of all /ppt/diagrams/data which are texts in `SmartArt` graphics we could do:

```
...
System.out.println("===========================================================================");

//additionally get all text out of all /ppt/diagrams/data which are texts in SmartArt graphics:
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (XSLFSlide slide : ((XMLSlideShow)slideshow).getSlides()) {
   for (org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart part : slide.getRelations()) {
    if (part.getPackagePart().getPartName().getName().startsWith("/ppt/diagrams/data")) {
     org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xmlObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(part.getPackagePart().getInputStream());
     org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = xmlObject.newCursor();
     while(cursor.hasNextToken()) {
      if (cursor.isText()) {
       sb.append(cursor.getTextValue() + "\r\n");
      }
      cursor.toNextToken();
     }
     sb.append(slide.getSlideNumber() + "\r\n\r\n");
    }
   }
  }
  String allTextContentInDiagrams = sb.toString();

System.out.println(allTextContentInDiagrams);
...
```